# The selected directory is not valid for Tomcat home: Windows 8.1

Tags: maven, tomcat

I installed apache-maven-3.2.5 at C:\ directory.

When I try to add tomcat-server from IntalliJ IDEA, I receive: "The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home"

Comment: Why such an old version of Apache Maven?

Comment: I forced to work with legacy-project